# Collision Detection Cocos 2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

Im trying to make a game where the ball randomly bounces around the screen and then if it hits the target you win the game. Therefore Im trying to create a collision detection between the ball sprite and the target sprite. The balls implementation is done in a separate class from the gameplay class and the target is added into the gameplay class like so:

```
-(void) targetCollision{

    CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"target.png"];
    target.position = ccp(400,50);
    [self addChild:target];


    CCSprite *ball = [[Ball alloc] init];
    [self addChild:ball];

    //CCSprite *ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball2.png"];
    //ball.position = ccp(400,75);
    //id a1 = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1 angle:360];
    //id repAct = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:a1];
    //[ball runAction: repAct];
    //[self addChild:ball];

    CGRect ballRect = [ball boundingBox];
    CGRect targetRect =  [target boundingBox];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ballRect, targetRect)) {
        NSLog(@"Target hit! Collision detected"); 
    }  
}
```

I can get this method to work if I add the ball with the commented out code but not this is not what I want to do. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: i can see that the ball and target is added and the ball keeps on rotating.. so your issue is with the movement of the ball??

Comment: well the ball movement is defined in a different class and is then added to the scene with the lines

CCSprite *ball = [[Ball alloc] init];
[self addChild:ball];

essentially there is a ball that randomly bounces around the screen and a stationary target. When the ball hovers over the target or collides with it I want the console to say that there has been a collision detected

Answer (score 0):

You should call you collision method inside schedule update or directly in schedule update method.
Something like this-

in your init method

```
[self scheduleUpdate];
```

in scheduleUpdate method you can call

```
[self targetCollision];
```

it will confirm collision as soon ball hit another ball

I hope it clears your problem

Answer (score -2):

how about use CCScheduler check the collision every minisecond